# Como realiza este sub-query en laravel? aparece este error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$fac = DB::table('amortizacion')
                  ->select('id_fac_enc')
                  ->where('id_amortizacion','=',$id)
                  ->get();
        $am = DB::table('amortizacion as a')
                ->join('cliente as c','c.id_cliente','a.id_cliente')
                ->select('nombre','nit','direccion','id_fac_enc','saldo')
                ->where('id_amortizacion','=',$id)
                ->get();
        $am2 = DB::table('amortizacion as a')
                ->join('cliente as c','c.id_cliente','a.id_cliente')
                ->select('nombre','nit','direccion','id_fac_enc','saldo')
                ->where('id_fac_enc','=',$fac)
                ->get();
```

Intento hacer que el query $am2, vaya a tomar el valor que devuelve el query de $fac pero siempre devuelve error, el query en mysql sencillamente se resuelve así: select * from amortizacion where id_fac_enc=(select id_fac_enc from amortizacion where id_amortizacion=1);

Comment: Que error devuelve?

Comment: ErrorException (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Tu error debe ir en la pregunta. Usa el boton [edit] y agregalo en la pregunta

Comment: ya cambie el titulo

Comment: Algun experto en laravel probablemente pueda ayudarte mas, pero tene en cuenta que $fac es un objeto, no un string. De alguna forma, tenes que acceder a las propiedades del mismo y obtener el valor del primer campo

Comment: por eso coloqué la consulta en mysql como yo la hago ¨select * from amortizacion where id_fac_enc=(select id_fac_enc from amortizacion where id_amortizacion=1);¨ ya que lo que necesito saber es si alguien puede hacerla ya sea con eloquent o query-builder

Answer (score 1):

Esto:

```php
$fac = DB::table('amortizacion')
                  ->select('id_fac_enc')
                  ->where('id_amortizacion','=',$id)
                  ->get();
```

Retorna un listado por más que tu sabes que solo va a haber un registro en el mismo. Entonces y sabiendo que solo debe haber uno puedes usar el método `first()`:

```php
$fac = DB::table('amortizacion')
                  ->select('id_fac_enc')
                  ->where('id_amortizacion','=',$id)
                  ->first();
```

Ya tendrás una sola fila, ahora solo hay que obtener el campo necesario de ésa fila.

```php
$fac_id = $fac->id_fac_enc;
```

Puedes leerlo en [laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results)

Answer (score 1):

Todos los querys que llegues a hacer con el facade `DB` siempre serán objetos, por lo tanto, no puedes hacer esto:

```
->where('id_fac_enc', '=', $fac)
```

Dado que `$fac` es un objeto.

Ahora, al hacer este query:

```
$fac = DB::table('amortizacion')
                  ->select('id_fac_enc')
                  ->where('id_amortizacion','=',$id)
                  ->get();
```

Cuando usas el método `get();` para obtener los resultados de tu consulta, te estará devolviendo una colección, por lo tanto tendrías que iterar sobre cada uno de los resultados:

```
$facs = DB::table('amortizacion')
                      ->select('id_fac_enc')
                      ->where('id_amortizacion', '=', $id)
                      ->get();

foreach($facs as $fac){
   echo 'El id es: ' . $fac->id_fac_enc;
}
```

Para obtener solo un registro de tu query tendrías que usar el método `first()`

```
$fac = DB::table('amortizacion')
                          ->select('id_fac_enc')
                          ->where('id_amortizacion', '=', $id)
                          ->first();

echo 'El id es: ' . $fac->id_fac_enc;
```

Entonces si tienes planeado que la primer consulta que estás tratando de hacer solo te devuelva un resultado, podrías agregar ese dato en la condición de la última consulta, primero comprobando, claro, que exista:

```
$am2 = DB::table('amortizacion as a')
                ->join('cliente as c', 'c.id_cliente', 'a.id_cliente')
                ->select('nombre', 'nit', 'direccion', 'id_fac_enc', 'saldo');
if($fac){
   $am2 = $am2->where('id_amortizacion', '=', $fac->id_fac_enc)
}

$am2 = $am2->get();

//Aquí ya tendrías que recorrer tus resultados    
foreach($am2 as $am){
       //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué tal si pruebas esto? Este expresión usando Querybuilder representa la misma consulta SQL que deseas hacer:

```
DB::table('amortizacion')->where('id_fac_enc', function($query) use ($id){
        $query->select('id_fac_enc')
        ->from('amortizacion')
        ->where('id_amortizacion', $id);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Podrias explicar que hace ese codigo? mira [answer]

Comment: Eloquent soporta subqueries mediante clousure para poder hacer la misma consulta en PHP que describe Mau: select * from amortizacion where id_fac_enc=(select id_fac_enc from amortizacion where id_amortizacion=1);

Comment: no me lo expliques a mi, explicalo en tu respuesta, a si la proxima persona que la vea entiende de que hablas ;)

Comment: con gusto, lo pondré aqui, el primer query va a traer unicamente un dato dependiendo del idkey de una tabla "x" y el siguiente trae todos los datos de una sola fila en específico de la tabla "x" y el tercero va a traer todos los registros que encuentre referente al valor del cierto campo, ya que va a coincidir en ese campo pero el valor del idkey va a hacer distinto, pueden ser varios.

Comment: fijate que si me funciona si dejo el 1 del ejemplo, pero cuando intento cambiar el 1 por el $id que trae esta funcion (public function show($id)) no me lo reconoce, por que sera?

Comment: Te actualizo el ejemplo para que sepas como pasar una variable a la función :)

Answer (score 0):

He tenido un error parecido y he encontrado una solución, la dejo aquí por si pude ayudar a alguien.

Mi propuesta sería cambiar las consultas por:

```
$fac = DB::table('amortizacion')
                  ->select('id_fac_enc')
                  ->where('id_amortizacion','=',$id)
                  ->pluck('id_fac_enc'); // Cambio get por pluck
        $am = DB::table('amortizacion as a')
                ->join('cliente as c','c.id_cliente','a.id_cliente')
                ->select('nombre','nit','direccion','id_fac_enc','saldo')
                ->where('id_amortizacion','=',$id)
                ->get();
        $am2 = DB::table('amortizacion as a')
                ->join('cliente as c','c.id_cliente','a.id_cliente')
                ->select('nombre','nit','direccion','id_fac_enc','saldo')
                ->whereIn('id_fac_enc', $fac) // Cambio Where por WhereIn
                ->get();
```

[WhereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-wherein) recibe los datos de un array y [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck) convierte la colección en un array de valores del tipo que se han pasado.